# Mapbox map is getting loaded before useEffect returns data

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have started learning react hooks and I want to load map on initial render with cooridnates which I get from the backend, but somehow my map is getting rendered before my api give the data back,
how do I make sure my map will wait till data is return ? do I need to put any condition on that?

below is api code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import { getBikeInfo, mapDetails } from './features/counter/getInfo/getDetails.js'

function App() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const dataToDisplay = useSelector(mapDetails);
    
    const mapContainer = useRef(null);

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidmloYW5nMTYiLCJhIjoiY2ttOHowc2ZhMWN2OTJvcXJ0dGpiY21pNyJ9.hK5Wxwby89E7tKWoBoY5bg';

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getBikeInfo())

        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: mapContainer.current,
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
            center: [-96, 37.8],
            zoom: 3
        });

        console.log('mapdetails:' + mapDetails)
        console.log('data display:' + dataToDisplay)
        
        map.on('load', function () {
            // Add an image to use as a custom marker
            map.loadImage(
                'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/custom_marker.png',
                function (error, image) {
                    if (error) throw error;
                    map.addImage('custom-marker', image);
                    // Add a GeoJSON source with 2 points
                    map.addSource('points', {
                        'type': 'geojson',
                        'data': {
                            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
                            'features': dataToDisplay
                        }
                    });

                    // Add a symbol layer
                    map.addLayer({
                        'id': 'points',
                        'type': 'symbol',
                        'source': 'points',
                        'layout': {
                            'icon-image': 'custom-marker',
                            // get the title name from the source's "title" property
                            'text-field': ['get', 'title'],
                            'text-font': [
                                'Open Sans Semibold',
                                'Arial Unicode MS Bold'
                            ],
                            'text-offset': [0, 1.25],
                            'text-anchor': 'top'
                        }
                    });
                }
            );
        });
    }, []);


    return (
        <div className="district-map-wrapper">
            <div id="districtDetailMap" className="map">
                <div style={{ height: "100%" }} ref={mapContainer}>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

below is my updated code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (dataToDisplay.length != 0) {
        loadtheMap
    }
}, []);
```

but after some refresh I see data is not getting populated and setting `dataDisplay` to `[]`.

update 1:
based on suggestion I have updated my code like this

```
if(!dataLoaded) { // do not render anything if you're not ready
  return ( 
  <div className="hidden">
  <div id="districtDetailMap" className="map">
      <div style={{ height: "100%" }} ref={mapContainer}>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>);
}
```

where *className="hidden"* is define in App.css like below

```
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

but still I am on same issue

as requested PFB my sandbox link

> [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-sea-j1qjl?file=/src/store.js)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `useEffect` you are basically guaranteed that your component will render once before it even initiates the query

If you want to ensure your component won't be rendered, use some flag to indicate that data is ready, set it to `true` after you set up your Map and conditionally render some fallback ui while this flag is `false`

```
function App() {
    const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState(false); // introduce the flag
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const dataToDisplay = useSelector(mapDetails);
    
    const mapContainer = useRef(null);

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidmloYW5nMTYiLCJhIjoiY2ttOHowc2ZhMWN2OTJvcXJ0dGpiY21pNyJ9.hK5Wxwby89E7tKWoBoY5bg';

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getBikeInfo())

        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: mapContainer.current,
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
            center: [-96, 37.8],
            zoom: 3
        });

        console.log('mapdetails:' + mapDetails)
        console.log('data display:' + dataToDisplay)
        
        map.on('load', function () {
            // Add an image to use as a custom marker
            map.loadImage(
                'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/custom_marker.png',
                function (error, image) {
                    if (error) throw error;
                    map.addImage('custom-marker', image);
                    // Add a GeoJSON source with 2 points
                    map.addSource('points', {
                        'type': 'geojson',
                        'data': {
                            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
                            'features': dataToDisplay
                        }
                    });

                    // Add a symbol layer
                    map.addLayer({
                        'id': 'points',
                        'type': 'symbol',
                        'source': 'points',
                        'layout': {
                            'icon-image': 'custom-marker',
                            // get the title name from the source's "title" property
                            'text-field': ['get', 'title'],
                            'text-font': [
                                'Open Sans Semibold',
                                'Arial Unicode MS Bold'
                            ],
                            'text-offset': [0, 1.25],
                            'text-anchor': 'top'
                        }
                    });
                    setDataLoaded(true); // set it to true when you're done
                }
            );
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="district-map-wrapper" style={dataLoaded ? undefined : {display: 'none'}}>
            <div id="districtDetailMap" className="map">
                <div style={{ height: "100%" }} ref={mapContainer}>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I want to put condition like when **dataToDisplay** then load, how should I do that?I added like if(dataToDisplay){ load} but it is not working

Comment: ok..I added like this if(dataToDisplay.length != 0){ load }it worked

Comment: after some reload again I am facing same issue

Comment: I have updated answer with code sample I think can help you

Comment: ** if(!dataLoaded) { // do not render anything if you're not ready
  return null;
}** after adding this line I am getting this error  Invalid type: 'container' must be a String or HTMLElement. at const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState(false);

Comment: It appears you have to mount your component before injecting the Map. In this case, I'd advise to hide this component not by returning null, but rather by using css property 'display: none' and adding it to styles of your div

Comment: sorry I am poor in CSS, can you please update your answer in that?

Comment: shouldn't it be false rather than undefined?

Comment: In this instance I think it makes no difference, but in general I prefer setting it as undefined to ensure the property does not end up in DOM node

Comment: I apologize but this doesn't work out, map is getting loaded without getting data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229975/discussion-between-lowcool-and-dkuznietsov).

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I guess I understood you incorrectly. Do you mind reproducing your example in codesandbox so I (and other people as well) might look at your issue closely?

Comment: added, please let me know you need more details in that